# How should we estimate accessibility testing for a waterfall project?

Tags: estimation, testing, waterfall

I am working with a lot of teams and there are different phases of testing.  We have devised a standardized process for accessibility testing across many different teams. This process is to be done for all new software applications, upgrades or enhancements. The problem is deciding how to estimate accessibility testing and incorporating it into a standard accessibility testing process for team leaders.

Comment: The number of times you've used the word "Process" and you've not asked people actually doing the work about this suggests agile isn't for you.

Comment: Hi Nathan - thanks for pointing it out.  I prefer agile and got mixed up in my terminology.  In work I am forced to use waterfall.  So sorry my title should have read waterfall.  i have edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is deciding how to estimate accessibility testing and incorporate it into this standard accessibility testing process for team leaders.

Accessibility testing is just testing. From a project management point of view, it's just another task, milestone, or gating activity that must be performed to complete a unit of work.

You estimate accessibility testing the same way you estimate the rest of your work packages: you use historical norms, or you ask subject-matter experts and/or assigned task-performers to provide an educated guess about how long they expect each task to take.

If this type of testing is new to your project, then your estimates are likely to be less accurate than you might like. If that's the case, you simply apply a fudge factor that represents your project's level of uncertainty about the tasks, and then re-estimate or adjust your schedule as the team's experience grows and your estimation practices improve.

Comment: Good answer thanks a million.  You have answered the question well.    I would have never thought of the fudge factor but it makes sense.  This type of testing is new to my multiple teams projects, you guessed correctly.  Thanks once again.